# Processing files in directories with multithreading

Tags: java, performance, multithreading

I am processing files in directories. I want to use multi-threading in two ways:

1. 10 threads to process files/folders concurrently
2. 10 threads to process all lines in each file concurrently

In this code, `FolderProcessor` implements (1), and `DocProcessor` implements (2). Is there any flaw in this implementation? My testing seems to show that (2) works and reduces time a lot, but (1) doesn't really reduce the processing time.

```
class FolderProcessor{   
      ...
 void processFolder(String inputPath, String outputPath){

            File inputFolder = new File(inputPath);
            String[] filenames = inputFolder.list();

            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            for (String filename : filenames) {
                String filePath = inputPath + filename;
                File inputfile = new File(filePath);
                if (inputfile.isDirectory()) {
                    processFolder(filePath, outputPath + filename);
                } else {
                    pool.execute(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            log.info("Start processing " + filePath);
                            Writer.write(filePath, outputPath);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            pool.shutdown();
            try {
                pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}

class DocumentWriter{
    ...
 public static void write(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        try {

            File test_output = new File(outputFile);
            test_output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            test_output.createNewFile();
            FileWriter write_test_output = new FileWriter(outputFile);

            List<Document> docs = DocPrecessor.processDocs(inputFile);
            for (Document doc : docs) {
               ...
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class DocPrecessor{
    ......
    public static List<Document> processDocs(String filePath) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Document> processedDocs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ...
        String line = null;
        int docNo = 0;
        List<Future<Document>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Callable<Document> callable = new TextThread(line, ++docNo);
            tasks.add(pool.submit(callable));
        }
        for (Future<Document> task : tasks) {
            try {
                processedDocs.add(task.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("InterruptedException Failure: " + line);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                log.error("Thread ExecutionException e: " + line);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return processedDocs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## FolderProcessor

```
if (inputfile.isDirectory()) {
    processFolder(filePath, outputPath + filename);
}
```

This is why you're not seeing any benefits from parallelism; you're processing subfolders within the same thread!  But even so, you'd be making a new `ExecutorService` each invocation; `pool` should be a class-level field:

```
private final ExecutorService pool;

public FolderProcessor(ExecutorService pool){
    this.pool = pool;
}
```

After running some tests, I noticed that your path resolution is broken; the path separator isn't being added for subpaths!  You can use all the operating system's rules by switching to `Path`s:

```
String filePath = inputFolder.toPath().resolve(filename).toString();
```

Some quick cleanup and a change to lambda notation (Java 8 is so much cleaner):

```
class FolderProcessor{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();
    private final ExecutorService pool;

    public FolderProcessor(ExecutorService pool){
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    void processFolder(String inputPath, String outputPath){
        File inputFolder = new File(inputPath);

        for (String filename : inputFolder.list()) {
            String filePath = inputFolder.toPath().resolve(filename).toString();
            String writeTo = new File(outputPath).toPath().resolve(filename).toString();
            if (new File(filePath).isDirectory()) {
                pool.execute(()->processFolder(filePath, writeTo));
            } else {
                pool.execute(()->{
                    log.info("Start processing " + filePath);
                    DocumentWriter.write(filePath, writeTo);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: My IDE warns me that `inputFolder.list()` could throw a `NullPointerException` if the `File` isn't a directory.  While your current usage ensures that it is, you may want to put in a check down the line.

## DocumentWriter

Since we're missing the meat of the method (the contents of the `for` loop), it's hard to make too many recommendations.  I am concerned with the shift in naming convention (Java uses camelCase), and the lack of checking for errors in file creation.  Also, you create a file and discard it as soon as you've made your checks, when you could save the `FileWriter` some work by passing it along.

After some cleanup:

```
class DocumentWriter{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();

    public static void write(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        try {
            File outputFile = new File(outputPath);
            if(outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()){
                outputFile.createNewFile();
                FileWriter outputWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);

                List<Document> docs = DocProcessor.processDocs(inputPath);
                for(Document doc : docs){
                    // Missing code
                }
            }else{
                // You may want to log this
                log.config("File could not be created: " + outputPath);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## DocProcessor

I assumed you wanted the typo fixed.  There's not much else to say about this class, since all the logic is either tied up in a class we can't see (`TextThread`) or omitted.  I will say that if you're running this method in parallel, you're going to be creating an `ExecutorService` for each invocation, possibly creating hundreds of threads.  A shared `ExecutorService`, (could be static, but preferably a final instance variable) would be a better solution.

## Other Notes

You probably want to use `Executors.newWorkStealingPool(10)` since it keeps the threads active while waiting for I/O operations, which will give you better performance.  `newFixedThreadPool(10)` tends to work better for CPU-intensive operations as opposed to I/O-intensive operations.

Comment: " pool.execute(()->processFolder(filePath, writeTo));" this line doesn't compile. What's the arrow? Also, where is the Runnable?

Comment: It compiles in Java 8, and it's called Lambda Notation.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html  If your language level is less than 8, you can replace with `pool.execute(new Runnable(){public void run(){processFolder(filePath, writeTo);}});`, although I recommend updating to 8, since 7 was phased out in 2015. https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml

Comment: I am using Java 8.  Maybe there is a little syntax error in the code? Please double check. It is complaining the processFolder()'s arguments.

Comment: Yes, it's the typo error. sorry.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/osiwutiful.java is what I'm using.  It compiles and runs fine.

Comment: for the new design, should I move the pool.shutdown and the subsequent try{} block out of the processFolder() method? It should be shutdown once only. Right?

Comment: Yes.  You pass the method an `ExecutorService` to use, and shut it down after the method has executed.  See the link above and check the `main` method for an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62033/discussion-between-user697911-and-ndm13).

Comment: @user697911: Would you please accept this answer ? It is a really good solution and ndm13 really put a lot of work into it